# What is the recommended way for handling a multilingual service?

Tags: services, i18n-l10n

I'm using the Services module together with a multilingual backend (field translation). My endpoint is v1. What I would like to have is `<domain>/v1/fr/...`.

Is this possible without having a redirect?
What is the recommended way for handling multilingual services?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the language code as a URL prefix, then you should be able to access your endpoint as usual with the language code prefixed to it:

```
?q=fr/v1/...
```

For example, to get a node in *French* you could make a **GET** call on:

```
?q=fr/v1/node/123.json
```